# How to fetch data from server below recyclerview in android

Tags: android

I am trying to make show more data below recyclerview like endless scrolling ,the problem is that ,First I want to fetch data from url in Act onCreate and then again when scroll down send request and fetch data from server but data not comes below 5 data which I had fetched earlier instead of below data remove previous data and comes over that ,kindly help me.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String m_DealListingURL = "http://192.163.0.110:8080/ireward/rest/json/metallica/getDealListInJSON";
    public CJsonsResponse m_oJsonsResponse;
    public String s_szresult = "";
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private List<User> mUsers;
    private UserAdapter mUserAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitle("LoadMoreRecycleView");
        mUsers = new ArrayList<User>();

        new CDealDataSent().execute(m_DealListingURL);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mUserAdapter = new UserAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);

        mUserAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                Log.e("haint", "Load More");
                mUsers.add(null);
                mUserAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mUsers.size() - 1);

                //Load more data for reyclerview
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e("haint", "Load More 2");

                        //Remove loading item
                        mUsers.remove(mUsers.size() - 1);
                        mUserAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mUsers.size());

                        new CDealDataSent().execute(m_DealListingURL);
                    }
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
    }

    //sending deal data to retreive response from server
    public String DealListing(String url, CRegistrationDataStorage login) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        m_oJsonsResponse = new CJsonsResponse();
        try {
            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            String json = "";
            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("agentCode", "9555517491");
            jsonObject.put("pin", "05E0901648FD6439207FA74FC3E07734");
            jsonObject.put("recordcount", "5");
            jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", "0");
            //jsonObject.put("emailId", "nirajk1190@gmail.com");
            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            System.out.println("InputStream....:" + inputStream.toString());
            System.out.println("Response....:" + httpResponse.toString());

            StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
            System.out.println("statusLine......:" + statusLine.toString());
            ////Log.d("resp_body", resp_body.toString());
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // 10. convert inputstream to string
                if (inputStream != null)
                    s_szresult = m_oJsonsResponse.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                //String resp_body =
                EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            } else
                s_szresult = "Did not work!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("resul.....:" + s_szresult);
        // 11. return s_szResult
        return s_szresult;
    }

    static class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvEmailId;

        public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

            tvEmailId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailId);
        }
    }

    static class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public LoadingViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        }
    }

    //  sending deal data to server and retreive response......
    class CDealDataSent extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public JSONObject m_oResponseobject;
        public ProgressDialog m_PDialog;
        public CRegistrationDataStorage oRegisterStorage;
        public User item;

        //      @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            m_PDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            m_PDialog.setMessage("Please wait while Loading Deals...");
            m_PDialog.setCancelable(false);
            m_PDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return DealListing(urls[0], oRegisterStorage);// sending data to server...

        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            m_PDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                m_oResponseobject = new JSONObject(result);// getting response from server
                final JSONArray posts = m_oResponseobject.optJSONArray("dealList");

                mUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
                for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                    item = new User();
                    item.setName(post.getString("dealname"));
                    item.setEmail(post.getString("dealcode"));
                    mUsers.add(item);
                }
                getResponse();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void getResponse() throws JSONException {
            if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Transaction Successful")) {

                mUserAdapter = new UserAdapter();//creating object of adapter and addd setting odata to adapter for use.
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);//adding adapter to recyclerview
            } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connection not avaliable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    }

    class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
        private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;

        private OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener;

        private boolean isLoading;
        private int visibleThreshold = 5;
        private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;

        public UserAdapter() {
            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                    totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                        if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                            mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                        }
                        isLoading = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener) {
            this.mOnLoadMoreListener = mOnLoadMoreListener;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return mUsers.get(position) == null ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.layout_user_item, parent, false);
                return new UserViewHolder(view);
            } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_item, parent, false);
                return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            if (holder instanceof UserViewHolder) {
                User user = mUsers.get(position);
                UserViewHolder userViewHolder = (UserViewHolder) holder;
                userViewHolder.tvName.setText(user.getName());
                userViewHolder.tvEmailId.setText(user.getEmail());
            } else if (holder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
                LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;
                loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mUsers == null ? 0 : mUsers.size();
        }

        public void setLoaded() {
            isLoading = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you have written these 2 lines `mUsers.remove(mUsers.size() - 1);
                    mUserAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mUsers.size());`?

Comment: for testing ....what is the correct way

Comment: What about these lines `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("agentCode", "999999999");
        jsonObject.put("pin", "05E0901648FD6439207FA74FC3E07734");
        jsonObject.put("recordcount", "5");
        jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", "0");`?

Comment: here I post data to server to fetch deals of that number ....

Comment: This `lastcountvalue` is for what?

Comment: here record count is : how many deals we want to show and lastCountvalue is : deals shown previously

Comment: when i open app in oncreate i fetched 5 deals and then in mAdapter.setOnLoadListener again i hit server gives me five more deals but it is shown over previous deal but i want below.

Comment: Every time, no need to create the object of adapter and also you need to send some value from API whether there is any further data or not. If there is more data then pass `lastcountvalue` as number of record fetched all total before calling the API. And onResponse add that data to the list.

Comment: lastcount is for number of record fetched previously

Comment: I do that but fethced not below

Comment: remove previous fetched data and view new data

Comment: Fetch that and check whether there are more data or not. And maintain the loadmore functionality like that.

Comment: Can you post your response sample?

Comment: there is no more data

Comment: {"agentcode":"99999","vendorcode":"IRE","transid":"45551","resultcode":"0","resultdescription":"Transaction Successful","requestcts":"03/16/2016 13:21:03","responsects":" 03/16/2016 13:21:03","clienttype":" GPRS","destlanguage":" ","dealList":[{"dealname":"Es","dealvalue":"1","dealcode":"EST4","dealcategory":"0"},{"dealname":"Es","dealvalue":"1","dealcode":"EST4","dealcategory":"0"}] }

Comment: How you are deciding whether more data is there or not?

Comment: if more data has then number of data increase in "dealList"

Comment: You something told about load more functionality then how you are knowing more data is there or not and how you will call the API?

Comment: i dont know give me solution if you have

Comment: i want same as http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html

Comment: but there they static maintain records and i have to fetch dynamically ...

Comment: Yes, I understood you are fetching the records dynamically but, how you will know that there are more records?

Comment: see first i fetched data  in onCreate with recordcount:2,lastcount:0 and then next time hitting server  recordcount:4,lastcount:2

Comment: if there is no value then server gives me response,"response":"No Vlue"

Comment: Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

At first remove these two lines from `public void run()`

```
 mUsers.remove(mUsers.size() - 1);
 mUserAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mUsers.size());
```

and modify your `onPostExecute()` something to this

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    m_PDialog.dismiss();
    try {
        m_oResponseobject = new JSONObject(result);// getting response from server
        if(m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Deal List Not Found"))
              return;
        final JSONArray posts = m_oResponseobject.optJSONArray("dealList");
        if(isFirstTime) {
        mUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
        isFirstTime = false;
        } else {
        mUsers.remove(mUsers.size() - 1);
        mUserAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mUsers.size());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
            item = new User();
            item.setName(post.getString("dealname"));
            item.setEmail(post.getString("dealcode"));
            mUsers.add(item);
            mUserAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mUsers.size());
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Define `isFirstTime` variable and inside `onCreate()` initialize `isFirstTime = true;` before `new CDealDataSent().execute(m_DealListingURL);`

Comment: this answer where to pu on first hit or second hit

Comment: what is modification i have to do in mAdapter.setOnLoadListener

Comment: I already wrote what the modification need to do. And you need maintain a flag for first hit and second hi and need to manage that.

Comment: Which part unable to understand?

Comment: please friend help me

Comment: its two days i trying

Comment: i am not understand mAdapter.setOnLoadListener that how to ececute second hit

Comment: Just see my above code with description and let me know.

Comment: i undersatnd you code but how to call url from mAdapter.setOnLoadListener

Comment: You have written this line inside onLoadMore `new CDealDataSent().execute(m_DealListingURL);` this will call the API automatically.

Comment: mUserAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
           @Override
           public void onLoadMore() {
              Log.e("haint", "Load More");
              mUsers.add(null);
                mUserAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mUsers.size() - 1);
    Log.e("haint", "Load More 2");
   m_n_DefaultRecordCount = m_n_DefaultRecordCount + 5;
    m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount+ 5;
    sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);
    sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);
    new DealNext().execute(m_DealListingURL);
            }
        });

Comment: Where is the problem, I am unable to understand, the problem what I understood , I tried to solve and post that.

Comment: dear i  go through your way but on first hit got data from server .....but on second hit againg got response but not below first response list it remove first response by progress dialog

Comment: this is for first hit :-----

Comment: m_oResponseobject = new JSONObject(result);// getting response from server
    final JSONArray posts = m_oResponseobject.optJSONArray("dealList");

    mUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
     item = new User();
     item.setName(post.getString("dealname"));
     item.setEmail(post.getString("dealcode"));mUsers.add(item);

     mUsers.add(item);
    }

Comment: and this is for second hit:-----

Comment: m_oResponseobject = new JSONObject(result);// getting response from server
    final JSONArray posts = m_oResponseobject.optJSONArray("dealList");
    mUsers.remove(mUsers.size() - 1);
    mUserAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mUsers.size());
    mUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
     item = new User();
     item.setName(post.getString("dealname"));
     item.setEmail(post.getString("dealcode"));
     mUsers.add(item);
     mUserAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mUsers.size());

Comment: and this is for adapterlistener:-----

Comment: For the second hit remove `mUsers = new ArrayList<User>();` this line and try.

Comment: new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
      Log.e("haint", "Load More 2");

      m_n_DefaultRecordCount = m_n_DefaultRecordCount + 5;
      m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;

      sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);
      sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);
      new DealNext().execute(m_DealListingURL);


     }
    }, 5000);

Comment: after removing line you told works fine but on first hit it doubling data

Comment: You need to take a `Boolean` variable and check for if its first time then create new list otherwise add the element to the list.

Comment: @rahul check the modified answer once.

Comment: I inserted it on second time url hit ,but it doubling data instead of inserting and alson automatic hit server after 5seconds

Comment: here is my adapter.listener :

Comment: public void onLoadMore() {
    Log.e("haint", "Load More");
    mUsers.add(null);
    mUserAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mUsers.size() - 1);

    //Load more data for reyclerview
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
      Log.e("haint", "Load More 2");

      m_n_DefaultRecordCount = m_n_DefaultRecordCount + 5;
      m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;

      sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);
      sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);
      new DealNext().execute(m_DealListingURL);
}}, 5000);

Comment: also if there is no any deals in records i get response "resultdescription":"Deal List Not Found" from server

Comment: Put a condition before fetching the JSONArray and check with the resultDescription then write `return;`

Comment: and also hit url automatically how?

Comment: means url automatically hit after 5 seconds how can this occur i only put handler in adapter.listre

Comment: Study about android at first and do some basic programming and try.Its not a tutorial site.